# Future Proof Power Automate Approval Flows

Tags: approval-process, power-automate

I setup an Approval Flow (*first to respond*) that notifies one user that an item needs to approved or rejected. The approval process needs to be updated to include an additional approver.  That's simple enough, but there are currently 200+ approvals running and there's no simple OOB way to cancel or add users to the pending approvals.

Is it possible to assign an approval request to an o365 group?

My hope is that I can add/remove users from the o365 group and those users can manage pending approvals from the Power Automate portal.

Answer (score 0):

Power Automate doesn’t support O365 groups for Approval Action

Comment: you can send the approval request to the group email address but the users don't see pending approvals in the portal or app.